# .htaccess code has been hacked I can't load home page

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site was hacked and I believe by mistake I removed a line of coding from my htaccess file.

My index and .php includes won't load anymore.

My site is: romanlife-romeitaly.com

This is the code i am left with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.shtml$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you!

Sara

Comment: your .htaccess file looks fine

Comment: It shows hostgator page i guess your hosting provider has blocked or removed your site better to consult with them